# NotFound 404 error when tring to make a query to bigquery-public-data

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to query in python.

This is my code:

```
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
        SELECT city
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.openaq.global_air_quality`
        WHERE PL
        """

query_job = client.query(query)
```

and the error I get is a NotFound 404:

```
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /bigquery/v2/projects//jobs?prettyPrint=false was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

I know that this table exists but I don't know why it can find it. I am following a kaggle course on SQL and there it works flawlessly. I have tried copying the exact code into google colab, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: I am working in google colaboratory, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Have you created a new GCP project for your kaggle course ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really sure what that is, I'm also completely new to google cloud. Would you give me more detailed instructions please?

Comment: In order to run the query in your code, you need to have a GCP project and also a permission to access BigQuery on the GCP project.  I mean I wonder you set up this prerequisite in advance before you run the python script in your jupyter notebook.  If you're following the kaggle course, you'd better checkt that out first.

Comment: Also there is no `PL` column inside the public dataset `bigquery-public-data.openaq.global_air_quality`.

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided the complete details of your project,

```
pid = "Project_id"
client = bigquery.Client(pid)

query = """
        SELECT city
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.openaq.global_air_quality`
        WHERE PL
        """

query_job = client.query(query)
```

Hope this will work.